# Start polling when flag becomes true

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

I want to start polling when the value of atrribute becomes true, is there any method to start  to poll when the flag becomes true, right now my implementation is :

```
 ngOnInit(){
        //want to start when startedPoll becomes true otherwise dont
        let url = 'getStatus'
        this.pollingSubscribe = interval(5000).pipe(
          switchMap(() => this.http.getCall(url))
        ).subscribe(data => {
          if(data['success']) {
            this.pollingData =data['result']

            this.processData(this.pollingData)
          }

        }, error =>{
          this.error = true;
          this.errorData = this.createPollingFiles;
        })
      }

startPoll(){
  this.startedPoll = true;
}
```

when ***startedPoll*** becomes **true** start to poll data, please don't suggest the **if and else** implementation

Comment: Just move the content of ngOnInit inside startPoll()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only way `startedPoll` can become `true` is when the `startPoll` method is called, then simply move the `subscribe` call from your `ngOnInit` method into `startPoll`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // want to start when startedPoll becomes true otherwise dont
    let url = 'getStatus'
    this.pollingObservable = interval(5000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.http.getCall(url))
    );
}

startPoll() {
    this.pollingSubscribe = this.pollingObservable.subscribe(data => {
        if (data['success']) {
            this.pollingData = data['result']
            this.processData(this.pollingData)
        }
    }, error => {
        this.error = true;
        this.errorData = this.createPollingFiles;
    })
    this.startedPoll = true;
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.pollingSubscribe) {
        this.pollingSubscribe.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**Ensure that `startPoll` is not called more than once while polling is active.**  Otherwise, the `Subscription` which is already stored in `this.pollingSubscribe` will be lost, polling will be doubled in frequency, and some polling will continue after the component is destroyed.

Comment: how can i unsubscribe  the subscription i called it on ngDestroy but still  polling is working

Comment: `ngOnDestroy() { this.pollingSubscribe.unsubscribe(); }`

Comment: yes using the same code i can still see the api calls

Comment: Then the most likely cause is that you're making another subscription to the `pollingObservable` somewhere else in your code.  Anywhere that you have a `subscribe` call, you should be storing the returned `Subscription` for unsubscribing later.

Comment: ngOnDestroy() { console.log('destroying'); this.pollingSubscribe.unsubscribe(); }

Comment: Oh, are you calling `startPoll` more than once?  If you are, then previous subscription handles are being lost.

Comment: yep start poll is a continuous function

Comment: how can i keep track and unsub all subscription

Comment: You don't want multiple subscriptions.  If you have one subscription, polling happens once every 5sec.  If you have two, polling happens twice every 5sec.  If you never want to poll more than once every 5sec, you must not have multiple subscriptions.